How to run a function with the same name as a std::string?
I am dealing with chromium's IPC library. As a simple description, when a message is received, the following function is called.
bool Execute(const std::string& name, const std::vector<value_type>& arguments);

name contains the message name and arguments is a list of values passed in for processing. I already have about 30 different kinds of messages and growing. As an  obvious extraction, instead of handling everything in execute, I created a function per type of message. So now Execute looks as such:
bool Execute(const std::string& name, const std::vector<value_type>& arguments)
{
    if (name == "func1")
        return func1();
    else if (name == "func2")
        return func2();
    else if (name == "func3")
        return func3();
    else if (name == "func4")
        return func4();
    else if (name == "func5")
        return func5();
    else if (name == "func6")
        return func6();
    ...
}

name will always have the same value as the function to be called. Is there a way to eliminate this massive chain of if statements (turning to a switch does not count)? Additionally, all possible name's will be known at compile-time, but I cannot template this as technically name is not a compile time string.

An std::unordered_map with functions as values (assuming the functions have identical signatures), stored as pointer to function type, or as std::function

you can use a std::unordered_map<std::string,std::function<void()>> (but don't expect it to be better than a switch, neither performance wise nor amount of typing, you will need to spell out the mapping between function and string, unless.... no, please no macros ;)

The strings and function pointers are all static constants, so you could use a global std::map<std::string, ...> to store the mapping.
This would bring the mapping semantics together in a more maintainable way and as a bonus, take advantage of the lookup optimizations in map.
